# Change CSS font of the Google Search Form?

Tags: html, css, forms, design-patterns, developer-tools

I have this css search form on the left top, above the flags. Please see this [LINK](https://neculaifantanaru.com/un-cec-pentru-schimbarea-ta.html)

> ```
> <form action="https://neculaifantanaru.com/search.html" method="get" id="site-search">
>     <fieldset>
>         <!-- <label for="search">Cauta in site</label> -->
>         <input type="text" name="q" id="q" value="" />&nbsp;&nbsp;
>         <button type="submit" class="btn btn-inverse">cauta</button>
>     </fieldset>
> </form>
> ```

I made this css:

> ```
> #site-search {float:right;width:240px;margin:0;padding:0px 0px 0px 0px;font-size:11px;background:#white;}
> #site-search LABEL {display:inline-block;font-size:11px;color:#red;}
> #site-search INPUT {width:140px;height:22px;margin:90;padding:0px 9px 0px;border-color:#yellow;background:#blueviolet;font-size:11px;}
> #site-search BUTTON {width:45px;height:22px;padding:0;margin:90;font-size:11px;line-height:13px;}
> ```

I want to change the css above, in order to look like this. [LINK 2](https://neculaifantanaru.com/en/index.html) So, what should I change on my css for this?

Answer (score 1):

Remove the styles and try with these styles. May be helpful :)

```
<form action="https://neculaifantanaru.com/search.html" method="get" id="site-search">
    <fieldset>
        <!-- <label for="search">Cauta in site</label> -->
        <input type="text" name="q" id="q" value="" />&nbsp;&nbsp;
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-inverse">cauta</button>
    </fieldset>
</form>

<style>

fieldset{ border: none;}
input { background-color: #ffff82; border: 1px solid #cccccc; }
button { background-color: #fff; color: blue; font-weight: bold; font-family: sans-sarif; border: none; border-top: 1px solid #0d6295; border-right: 1px solid #0d6295; font-size: 15px; }

</style>
```

Comment: yes, in Opera browser it looks good, but in mozilla or Chrome it doesn't look good. And must be. Can you please modify the css also to look good for chrome and mozilla firefox ?

Comment: also, you can delete the tags <fieldset> and </fieldset>, I think it's more confusing :)